# Django unittesting fails with CIText and Sqlite

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I use CIText from django.contrib.postgres, how can I carry on using SQlite with my unit tests ?

At the moment django dies trying to run my tests with:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: ...gmodel" ALTER COLUMN "name" TYPE citext USING "name"::citext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use database-specific features, your application becomes dependent on that particular database.

If the dependencies on the app using `citext` are minimal, you could create a separate settings file for testing that does not include this app.

That obviously limits your test coverage and is only suitable for quick local testing. On a CI system, you definitely want to use the database you are using in production anyways.

Comment: I thought this might be the case.  The reason I didn't implement something like CIText myself was to avoid edgecases and write a bunch of tests.   Having said that, it might be OK for unit testing, I think I'll have MockCIText

Comment: Sqlite has COLLATE nocase which seems to do the same thing, so I'm going to try a django feature request around it.

Comment: Every time we run the database it creates the test database and delete it after the test is complete. So Each time I am trying to run the tests django tries to create test_database, but the problem with my program is that it needs `citext` for the models to migrate. hence tt is getting failed throwing the error that `citext not found` is there any way i can create `citext` extension at the time test database is created ?